# Firefox on ubuntu not displaying image

Tags: jquery, css, image, firefox, yii

But in source code showing the image why? Did I something wrong. in Chrome displaying.

in my php file

```
<?php foreach ($images as $image): ?>
    <div class="row">
         <img style="display: block !important" width="301" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/ads/ad-'.$advert['id'].'/'. $image ?>" alt="something">
     </div>
<?php  endforeach ?>
```

on output in sitecontroller works fine(displaying image), but in my controller showing this

```
<div class="row">
<img style="display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important;   opacity: 0 !important; background-position: 301px 0px;" width="0" src="/yii/blog/images/ads/ad-205/3a30be93eb45566a90f4e95ee72a089a.png" alt="something" height="0"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Open the developer tools. Look in the net tab. Check to see if the right URL is being requested. Check to see if the response is correct.

Comment: <pre><img width="300" alt="something" src="/yii/blog/images/ads/ad-207/ac6b3cce8c74b2e23688c3e45532e2a7.png" class="eyscymmvqbhruzosqpaf"><code> firebug says Unable to load the specified url(I just translated on russian)

Comment: even alt not showing

Comment: And now chrome not displaying

Comment: <div class="row">
        <?php foreach ($images as $image): ?> 
        <img width="300" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/ads/ad-'.$advert['id'].'/'. $image ?>" alt="something">      <br />  
        <?php  endforeach ?> 
       </div>

Comment: <img width="0" src="/yii/blog/images/ads/ad-205/3a30be93eb45566a90f4e95ee72a089a.png" alt="something" height="0" style="display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important; opacity: 0 !important; background-position: 300px 0px;"/>

Comment: i am using yii framework, what is hiding my img

Comment: Has nothing to do with Firefox/yui, it has to do with the add ons you installed. `firefox -safe-mode.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have adblock add-on installed?
I had the same issue and found out somehow adblock considered the image an ad and hence blocked it.
if you have that installed disable adblock and try reloading page

Comment: DING DING DING!! Url has `/ads/ad` in it and any generic filter will block it.